# On Cloudwatch Dashboard want to show ebs environment health metrics with health codes

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ebs

I am using cloudwatch dashboards to have and aggregated view of various services running for the application. I have number widget for the EnvironmentHealth metrics which displays the enumerated values but not the health codes as OK, WARN .. On the beanstalk monitoring option I can see the service health but want the same on dashboard. Please help.

[This is what I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uNsm.png)

[This is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9NWy.png)

Comment: Which items of EBS do you want to put on the dashboard? For example state like in-use, Volume status like okay...

Comment: I am looking for the EnvironmentHealth metric on the dashboard for the dimension : EnvironmentName. Please refer to the newly added imgs of what I see v/s what I expect.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood ElasticBeanstalk for EBS(ElaticBlockStore). I tried some lambda code and worked fine like below.

Comment: Oh. my bad, now I did correct it to beanstalk. I did see that using lambda was an option but was curious if there is a way to avoid that and get the health code directly in metrics. Thanks a lot Shimo for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudWatch metrics for ElasticBeanstalk EnvironmentHealth [only returns numbers.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/health-enhanced-cloudwatch.html#health-enhanced-cloudwatch-metrics) 0 is OK, 1 is info, 15 warning etc.

Not sure this is the best way but using [custom widget](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/add_custom_widget_dashboard.html) with a lambda funcation works fine. The lambda function get the info of EB status and return it to CW dashboards.

**Create Lambda function**

I used python 3.9. Default setting is ok but note attach lambda IAM policy `AWSElasticBeanstalkReadOnly` to get EB status.

Lambda python code is below:

- set `EnvironmentName` for your EB env
- font size="56 px" color="#444444" are same as CW dashboard widget
- Create in the same region as EB env.

```py
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):

    client = boto3.client("elasticbeanstalk")

    response = client.describe_environment_health(
        EnvironmentName="<your-env-name>", AttributeNames=["HealthStatus"]
    )

    output = (
        """<font size="56 px" color="#444444">"""
        + response["HealthStatus"]
        + """</font>"""
    )

    return output
```

**Create Custom widget on CloudWatch dashboard**

Add widget -> Custom widget -> Next -> Select the Lambda function above -> Create widget

---

This is my dashboard.

[image]